# A Paley–Wiener theorem for a Volterra equation on compact operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $k(t) \in \mathcal{L}(E; E)$, $t \geq 0$ be a family of compact operators on a Banach space $E$, such that
$$ \int_0^\infty \lVert k(t)\rVert dt < \infty. $$
Let $r(t) \in \mathcal{L}(E; E)$ be the solution of integral equation
$$\forall t \geq 0, \quad r(t) = k(t) + \int_0^t{ k(t-s) r(s) ds}. $$
The integral with respect to $s$ is well-defined as an Bochner integral and $k(t-s)r(s)$ is the composition of $k(t-s)$ and $r(s)$.
For $\Re(z) \geq 0$, denote by $\hat{k}(z) = \int_0^\infty{e^{-zt} k(t) dt}$ the Laplace transform of $k$. Assume that
$$\forall z \in \mathbb{C} \text{ with } \Re(z) \geq 0, \quad  I - \hat{k}(z) \text{ is invertible}, $$
where $I$ stands for the identity operator on $\mathcal{L}(E; E)$.
It is true that $\int_0^\infty{\lVert r(t)\rVert dt} < \infty$ ?

---

It is easy to check that the condition on the Laplace transform is required for $r \in L^1(\mathbb{R}_+; \mathcal{L}(E;E))$. Indeed, when $r \in L^1(\mathbb{R}_+; \mathcal{L}(E;E))$, we have for $\Re(z) \geq 0$: $(I+\hat{r}(z))(I-\hat{k}(z)) = (I-\hat{k}(z))(I+\hat{r}(z)) = I $, so $I-\hat{k}(z)$ is invertible. When $dim(E) < \infty$, it is known that this condition is sufficient by the Paley–Wiener theorem [1, Th. 4.1]. I am particularly interested by the case where for all $t \geq 0$, $k(t)$ is a Hilbert–Schmidt operator on a separable Hilbert space $E$. Also, I would be already be happy with the slightly weaker conclusion:
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \quad \int_0^\infty{e^{-\epsilon t } \lVert r(t)\rVert dt } < \infty. $$

[1]: Gripenberg, G. ; Londen, S.-O. ; Staffans, O. [Volterra integral and functional equations](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511662805).

Comment: Spelling note: almost certainly you meant [Paley–Wiener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley–Wiener_theorem) (not ‘Palay’).  I edited accordingly.

Comment: If we are in a separable Hilbert space $H$, why don't we just use a family of finite-dimensional spaces $H_n$ expanding to $H$ and the corresponding family of orthogonal projections $P_n$? We have $\|P_nk(t)P_n-k(t)\|\to 0$ point-wise (due to compactness) and $\|k(t)\|$ is the integrable majorant, so $P_nkP_n$ tends to $k$ in $L^1$, after which we can approximate $P_nkP_n$ (and, thus, $k$) by a $C_0^\infty$ operator-valued function $k_1(t)$ in $L^1$ and mimic the Newman proof of Wiener's theorem (https://www.ams.org/proc/1975-048-01/S0002-9939-1975-0365002-8/S0002-9939-1975-0365002-8.pdf )?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do something in this spirit. If $k_n(t) = P_n k(t) P_n$, I believe that $I - \hat{k}_n(z)$ is indeed invertible for all $\Re(z) \geq 0$, provided n is large enough.  So by the standard Paley-Wiener's theorem, there exists $r_n \in L^1(\mathbb{R}_+)$ such that $r_n(t)= k_n(t) + \int_0^t{k_n(t-s) r_n(s) ds}$. Now my main problem is how to check that $sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_0^\infty{ \lVert r_n(t) \rVert dt} < \infty$ ? Did I miss something? I don't see how to mimic the proof of Newman here.

Comment: "I don't see how to mimic the proof of Newman here." Just follow it *literally* until you hit the non-commutativity issue and show us where you get. There is a small trick in the end, which is to freeze the non-smooth entries before looking at the FT of the convolution, but let's go over Newman's scheme first: it is very elegant and powerful, so I'd rather let you try it yourself. BTW, when responding to me, you'd better add @fedja somewhere, so that I would be alerted that something is going on :-)